# Java regex not matching the string "abc.txt" with pattern "abc"

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to match a string using java regex.

My string is "abc.txt" which is a file name.
The regex I am using is "abc".

```
String fileName = "abc.txt";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abc");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

But some how it does not match.
Infact using notepad++ regex search, it matches completely fine.

Please help

Comment: `matches()` looks for complete matches and not just for partial matches. Unless your regex matches the whole string, it wont match. In you case, a proper fileName would be `abc` or the proper regex `abc\\.txt`

Comment: try abc.* ?
In fact it depends what strings you want to match in the end